# Expand Pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

The tensor `a` in shape of `torch.Size([2, 2, 1, 2])`
how to expand this tensor to the shape of `torch.Size([2, 4, 1, 2])` without using `for` loop which takes time

For example, I have tensor `a`

```py
>>> print(a, a.shape)
tensor([[[[0.2955, 0.8836]],

         [[0.7607, 0.6657]]],


        [[[0.6779, 0.5109]],

         [[0.0785, 0.6564]]]]) torch.Size([2, 2, 1, 2])
```

I want to expand it to become tensor `b`

```py
>>> print(b, b.shape)
tensor([[[[0.2955, 0.8836]],

         [[0.2955, 0.8836]],

         [[0.7607, 0.6657]],

         [[0.7607, 0.6657]]],


        [[[0.6779, 0.5109]],

         [[0.6779, 0.5109]],

         [[0.0785, 0.6564]],

         [[0.0785, 0.6564]]]]) torch.Size([2, 4, 1, 2])
```

I tried `torch.expand()` but it only expands when the dimension=1.
How to achieve this format? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pytorch provides multiple functions with different styles to repeat the tensors. The function that you are looking for is named [repeat_interleave](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.repeat_interleave.html). Simple example:

```py
>>> a.repeat_interleave(2,dim=1)
tensor([[[[0.2955, 0.8836]],

         [[0.2955, 0.8836]],

         [[0.7607, 0.6657]],

         [[0.7607, 0.6657]]],


        [[[0.6779, 0.5109]],

         [[0.6779, 0.5109]],

         [[0.0785, 0.6564]],

         [[0.0785, 0.6564]]]])
```